# Regression Algorithm while passing in future values?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, algorithms

Very similar to this question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406416/including-future-values-in-a-regression

Is it possible to pass future (expected) values into a regression algorithm in order to tune the results.

For example, training & predicting stock market prices but with 3 predictions, 1 if macroeconomic factor increases by x% (such as inflation or interest rates), 1 if it decreases by x% and 1 if it stays the same?

What regressions machine learning algorithms allow us to pass in the future expected values to see multiple "what-if" predictions?

EDIT: To explain a bit further. I would like to predict Time-Series based data while passing in an additional independent variables (other than time). Is this possible & if so, which algorithms allow it?

Comment: Are the other independent variables really independent? Generally speaking, if we add variables, it's because there is some correlation (=dependency) to improve the result.

Comment: @NicolasMartin I might have used the wrong term. I want to pass a variable into the model that has already been precalculated for the future to assist with the prediction. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Is it a multi-variate time-series forecast?

If yes, you can add several features that could improve predictions.

The most common one is using LSTM neural networks:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/

But you might have better results with XGBoost:

https://cprosenjit.medium.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-using-xgboost-1728762a9eeb

If you have several features that don't change much with time, random forest could be interesting:

https://towardsdatascience.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-using-random-forest-2372f3ecbad1

In every case, some data analysis to know the correlations in your data and some patterns could be necessary before choosing the right algorithm:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/10/a-comprehensive-guide-to-time-series-analysis/